# Consuming locally hosted SOAP service via ANDROID APP

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm currently working on a project where I want to consume a soap web service which is written in C# running on `http://localhost:9063/WebService1.asmx` via a android application. My database is in wampserver(mysql). I am exposing my database via soap web service written in C# to android application.

currently my android app and the localhost is on the same network(wifi). I want to invoke the soap service `http://localhost:9063/WebService1.asmx` via android application. I'm trying to communicate with the locally hosted web service from another machine via postmen while in the same network. But it fails to communicate with each other.

when i try access the soap service locally via postman i am getting this error too
[image: error]
Any tips on how to get this done would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you are using ip adress instead of  `localhost` when trying to access it from another machine

Comment: Where is your app running? And what has that other machine to do with it?

Comment: yep..im using the ip addresses which is assigned by the router

Comment: Where is your app running? The ip address of which device are you talking about?

Comment: i wanted to check weather it is accessible via another machine when specifying the ip and wanted to check the invocation is working fine via postmen POST request

Comment: The ip address of which device?

Comment: ip address of soap service hosted device

Comment: `. I'm trying to communicate with the locally hosted web service from another machine via postmen while in the same network. But it fails to communicate with each other.`. So your problem has nothing to do with Android or an Android app. Your server is unreachable in your network. Just solve that.

Comment: Where is your app running?

Comment: my mobile app is running on my mobile phone, My soap service is running on my local machine..i want to call soap service through my router which both my machine and mobile app is connected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159038/discussion-between-selaka-nanayakkara-and-greenapps).

Comment: Ok. Now you are clear. You could have said that right away. But as you cannot connect to the service from another machine in your network your problem has nothing to do with Android. So make your service reachable in your network. Thats all.

Comment: when i am trying check the connectivity of the soap service through postman invoking i am getting this error.. check the edit issue

Comment: What are you complaining now? Your service is reachable by postman from that other machine! You see they communicate. Only there is some error. Find out what the error description means. And from your Android app on your Android device you should be able too to connect.

Comment: My god... Now you confused me completely. So i see now that you used postman not on that other machine but on the service machine. Forget what i said about connectivity. You service is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says **`Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1`** you should check your web service if you have implemented the data read part correctly.

"Data at the root level is invalid" means that you have attempted to parse something that is not an XML document.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... may be because of the json conversion that i am returning the result...

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara great!